# Button work on emulator but not on real phone

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-button

I have one button that when its pressed it show a banner ad and one button that when its pressed show an interstitial ad. Everything works fine on emulator but when i instal apk on my phone the buttons are not working. no ads are showing.
Here is the code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    AdView mAdView;

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3390312271613671/2240901449");

        Button buttonBanner = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBanner);
        Button buttonIntertitial = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonInterstitial);

        buttonBanner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
            }
        });

        buttonIntertitial.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

This is the xml code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonInterstitial"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="105dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bcgrimg"
        android:text="Interstitial ads"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonBanner" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonBanner"
        android:layout_width="203dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bcgrimg"
        android:text="banner ads"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonInterstitial"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3390312271613671/3145970768"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.333"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: did you read the logcat , please check  if you are getting this message "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet"

Comment: There can be multiple reasons that ad is not loading ! please share the logcat inorder to fix the actual problem !